# onclick="alert(ping.test);" gives undefined

Tags: javascript

```
<body>
   <script>
    ping = new Object;
    ping.test = '1234';
   </script>

<a href="#" onclick="alert(ping.test);">Test</a>
</body>
```

why is this working in IE8 but not in Firefox or chrome ?
The popup gives "undefined" in FF v5 and Chrome v12 , it gives "1234" in IE9.

Comment: That should work, though many things could be improved.

Comment: You should also specified the script type: type="text/javascript"

Comment: Mrchief, I'm using FF5 and Chrome 12. and its not working. Am I doing something illegal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a scope issue. Try this:

```
<body>
   <script>
    var ping = {};
    ping.test = '1234';
   </script>

<a href="#" onclick="alert(ping.test);">Test</a>
</body>
```

Edit: this works for me

```
<body>
   <script>
    var ping = {};
    ping.test = '1234';

    function test(){
        alert(ping.test);
    }
   </script>
<a href="#" onclick="test();">Test</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks ilia, but still have "undefined" with Chrome V.12 and FF 5.0

Comment: just tried with var ping = {};  still FF5 gives undefined. You guys think its a bug in FF5 and Chrome 12 ?

Comment: Thank you ilia. I will be using this method since its working on every browsers. I'm still a bit confused as to what's wrong with passing an object in an event handler in FF5 or Chrome12.

Comment: there are some good explanations here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224820/how-can-i-pass-arguments-to-anonymous-functions-in-javascript

Answer (score 4):

This is the inline event model (DOM Level 0) so only variables defined within its execution context will be used.

The following section

```
ping = new Object;
ping.test = '1234';
```

is in its own execution context when the interpreter goes through the page. Code in global scope will use the global object via `this`.

But here

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert(ping.test);">Test</a>
```

is a *separate execution*, which your browser views as an anonymous function. Using

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert(this);">Test</a>
```

Will not result in what we want. The line sees `window`, the `this` is actually being used for the current object that the inline event handler works with.

So ping is not defined within this context unless we allow it to be seen by referring to `window`.

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert(window.ping.test);">Test</a>
```

Now when the browser runs, it will grab the `window` global variable which in the (\script\) context will be the same as `this` and have access to to ping.test

Seen in the following browsers

- Google Chrome Mac 12.0.742.112
- Safari Version 5.0.5 (6533.21.1)
- Firefox Mac 3.6.18

**References**
[Mozilla Docs: this keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/this)
[Dom Events: inline model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events#Inline_model)

Answer (score 1):

`ping` has gone out of scope. Try this:

```
<body>
    <a href="#" id="test">Test</a>
    <script>
    var ping = new Object();
    ping.test = '1234';
    document.getElementById("test").onclick = function() { 
        alert(ping.test);
    };
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: how is ping out of scope? it's a global object at that point. (other than that, i think your general coding style is much better)

Comment: if you don't declare a variable with var, upredictable things happen to the scope.

Comment: Thanks Zach, the problem is, my application is very AJAX intensive. (using jquery "live" functionality is not really my best option)

Comment: You don't need to use JQuery live, if you re-select your objects in your AJAX callback function, you can accomplish the same effect.

Comment: if you don't declare with var, it's very predictable: the variable is put onto the global object. This is part of the JS spec

Comment: @James Deville: Where in the spec does it say that? I don't see it on p. 87 - 88, where variable declarations are covered. (http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)

Comment: @zach - if you follow the spec from the grammar parsing (11.13.1.1) to the reference lookup (10.2.2.1) to the internal PutValue call (11.13.1.5->8.7.2) you end up either throwing in strict mode (8.7.2.3.a) or assigning via a [[Put]] operation on the global object (8.7.2.3.b)