# Highcharts: Return PlotBands Click function via JSON

Tags: json, highcharts

I am using Highcharts and sending the xAxis options for plotBands from server in JSON format. I am trying to add the click method in the plotband. If I hard-code it in HTML file, all works fine, but when I send the dynamically generated code from server it plotband is shown but click does not work. I have taken the JSON output and put it directly in HTML file and it works there

My JSON Output:

```
[{"from":1349067600000,"to":1349758800000,"color":"rgba(68, 170, 213, .2)","events":{"click":"function(e) {alert(999);}"}},{"from":1350018000000,"to":1350622800000,"color":"rgba(68, 170, 213, .2)","events":{"click":"function(e) {alert(999);}"}}]
```

The code that works:

```
            plotBands:[ {from:Date.UTC(2012,09,01),to:Date.UTC(2012,09,05),color:'rgba(68, 170, 213, .2)',events:{click:function(e) {alert(999);}}},
                        {from:Date.UTC(2012,09,07),to:Date.UTC(2012,09,12),color:'rgba(68, 170, 213, .2)',events:{click:function(e) {alert(999);}}}
                    ],
```

The code that produces JSON from PHP:

```
$treatmentsList[$counter]=array('from'=>strtotime($PatPresVal->pres_med_start_date)*1000,'to'=>strtotime($PatPresVal->pres_med_end_date)*1000, 'color'=>'rgba(68, 170, 213, .2)','events'=>array('click'=>'function(e) {alert(999);}'));
```

I am sure its a small thing but I am unable to find it for hours...thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON does not generally support returning functions and especially not returning a function as a string as you have done:

```
"events":{"click":"function(e) {alert(999);}"}}
```

You could probably force it in using an `eval` but I'd discourage this.

A better bet would be to loop the plotBands object and add the event handler after you receive the JSON response:

```
for (var i = 0; i < plotBands.length; i++)
{
    plotBands[i]['events'] = {};
    plotBands[i]['events']['click'] = function(e) {alert(999);}
}
```

Comment: Mark, could you check the suggested edit, I can't see if it is correct, though I think so.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The second option worked. However, this has led me to work on a different issue. I designed this becuase I was planning to send the "data/DIV id/summary test" in function parameter for each plotband so that when the user triggers a click or mouseover event, I could enable/disable DIVs at the bottom of graphs to show the the start and end date, description, summary of plotband. ANy thoughts on that will help me. thanks for your support.

Comment: @owlstead, I have suggested the correction to Mark, unitll he approves it, it will not be visible to all. the first array for plotband needed to be there for iterator "i" to iterate.

Comment: @owlstead and FaisalKhan, thanks for the edits, answering questions a little too fast this morning, without checking my code.

Comment: @FaisalKhan, to answer your follow-up question, I believe you can return the DIV id as part of your JSON (say named someDiv), then do `var variable = plotBands[i]['someDiv']; plotBands[i]['events']['click'] = function(e) {alert(variable};}`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/224834/16363

Comment: @Mark. I got it working by using this: retData[1][i]['events']['mouseover'] = function(e) { $('#plotBandContent').html(this.label.text); I sent the label in JSON, hid it using style and getting its value from the above code. It created the exact user experience what I was trying for. Many thanks for your support.