# Functions as variables

Tags: javascript, function, variables, callback

Can someone share some knowledge on purpose of using function as variable in JavaScript?

And if I have the following code snippet

```
var error = function(param){
  /*Some coode*/
}
```

How can I pass parameter in the above function as call back function

```
onWorkFail(error)//how to pass value for param ??
```

And also in the following example,
is the operationCallback a variable here? What is the purpose of such declaration? Where do they come handy? I have seen these thing used my many developers but not yet able to figure out its significance.

```
var operationCallback =  {
      onsucess: function([some parameters]){
    },
    onfailure:failureFunction
}
function failureFunction(){
   /*some code here*/
}


function performOperation(){
    doSomeTask(operationCallback);
}
```

Comment: You can pass a parameter like with a "normal" function

Comment: When `onWorkFail` calls the function that it was given as an argument, it can pass in a `param` argument.

Comment: you store the function in the variable, pass it around etc. until you are ready to call it `()`

Comment: something like onWorkFail(error(param)) ??

Answer (score 1):

### Summary:

In javascript functions can be declared in two ways:

**function declarations:**

```
function foo () {}
```

**function expressions:**

```
const foo = function () {}
```

Your notation, that is passing functions as variables, is called a function expression. **An expression is just a line of code that evaluates to a value**. The value in this case is a **function object**.  This is all possible because in javascript functions are first class citizens. This means that functions can be passed around (in for example pararmeters, or variables) just like any other data.

### Why is this usefull?

When we have functions stored inside a variable or pass it as a parameter we can create higher order functions. Higher order functions are functions which take a function as an argument or return a function (or both). This can be very useful in various cases and JS even have some built in very convenient higher order function. For examle `map`.

```js
const arr = [1,2,3];

const doubleArr = arr.map((el) => el * 2);

console.log(doubleArr);
```

In the above example the `map` function takes a callback which is executed on every element of the array and then returns a new array.

---

### In your example:

```
var operationCallback =  {
      onsucess: function([some parameters]){
    },
    onfailure:failureFunction
}
```

operationCallback is an object. On this object are 2 properties which are both functions (methods associated with the object).

Comment: What about function constructor `var foo = new Function('x', 'return x')`

Answer (score -1):

(Lambdas are by definition anonymous functions that's what I think you mean by "Functions as variables")

That's not how lambdas work on JavaScript, take a look at this example:

```
var displayClosure = function() {
    var count = 0;
    return function () {
        return ++count;
    };
}
var inc = displayClosure();
inc(); // returns 1
inc(); // returns 2
inc(); // returns 3
```

Code by: Sergey Ilinsky [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224820/how-can-i-pass-arguments-to-anonymous-functions-in-javascript)

```
var myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");
var myMessage = "it's working";
myButton.onclick = function() { alert(myMessage); };
```

Comment: what about the second part of the question ?

Comment: Check the edit, it should help. I'm using an answer to other similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224820/how-can-i-pass-arguments-to-anonymous-functions-in-javascript

Comment: It seems you are trying to explain closures, while the OP has problems with understanding functions as first-class values